# タグ関連の未翻訳

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

- タグを全くウォッチしていないときのトップ右「Watch a tag」ボタン
- タグページの「Question tagged タグ名」
- 同ページ、「Watch Tag」ボタン
- 同ページ「Improve tag info」リンク
- 同ページ「Top users」
- 追記: 新規投稿時のタグ欄プレースホルダー

以上が未翻訳になっています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

現時点で翻訳が反映されたことを確認しました。